# DataAnnotations and Resources don't play nicely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, globalization, resx

I'm using dataannotations in an MVC2 app and am a little discouraged when trying to use RESX file resources for error messages.

I've tried the following but keep getting the exception "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = Resources.ErrorMessages.Required)]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = Resources.ErrorMessages.Required,
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages)]
```

I keep getting that error message unless I replace `ErrorMessageResourceName` with "Required" instead of `Resources.ErrorMessages.Required`.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing this right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing at the end is basically correct.  The `ErrorMessageResourceName` takes what the name implies, the *name* of a resource, not the resource itself.

`Resources.ErrorMessages.Required` points to the *actual* (localized) error message (resource). The *name* of the resource is simply "Required", and the *type* of the resource manager (used for `ErrorMessageResourceType`) is the class that contains that resource, in this case  the `Resources.ErrorMessages` class.

So your declaration should look like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

Comment: @devlife: No.  Not if you want localization.  That's exactly what the resource properties are for.  In fact, this is how it is with *any* localization, at some point in the chain you're going to have to look up a resource string based on the name, that's just how externalized resources work.  And this is still "strongly-typed" based on the resource class, you just don't have compile-time safety on the resource name itself.  If you want that, just create a class like `ResourceNames` with lines like `public const string Required = "Required"`, then you can specify those as the resource names.