# MVC 4 setting attributes values from resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources, asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource

I am trying to the following thing:

```
 [Display(Name = Resources.LcmsBs.Models.UserName)]
 [ToolTip(Resources.LcmsBs.ToolTips.UserName)]
 public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I am getting the following compilation error :

**An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type**

What is the best practice to avoid hard coded constants in code ?
Is it possible to set attributes values from the resources ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a slightly different question but the answer to the following could be applied to your question

[DataAnnotations and Resources don't play nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451150/dataannotations-and-resources-dont-play-nicely)

Something like the following

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.LcmsBs.Models), Name = "UserName")]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using c# version 6.0 or above, the best way could be:

```
[Display(Name = nameof(Resources.LcmsBs.Models.UserName), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.LcmsBs.Models))]
```